# JavaScript - JSON does not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

This is my first time working with JSON and I need to display this JSON http://www.rockfm.mx/jsonApps/jsonAlAire.php on a webpage that is not on the same server as the JSON I know I have to use JSONP but my code is not working at all here it is an example

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
});
$("#loaduserdata").click(function(){
    $("#userdata tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON(
        "www.rockfm.mx/jsonApps/jsonAlAire.php",
        function(data){
            $.each(data.userdata, function(i,user){
                var tblRow =
                    "<tr>"
                    +"<td>"+user.tituloDelShow+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+user.locutores+"</td>"
                    +"</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            });
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried with correct URL - one with **http(s)://** in front?

Comment: *"i know i have to use jsonp"* The service doesn't seem to support JSONP (or CORS), unless they use different URL arguments. You should read it's documentation. If it doesn't support JSONP, you can't make an Ajax call to it.

Comment: ^^^ I'm getting same-origin errors, no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, and JSONP doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: You probably need to write a script in php on your own server using something like cURL to get the json and make an ajax call to that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think that  the problem is the same origin security policy. 
My opinion is that the only solution is to use a php script on your own server that act as a gateway between your ajax and the remote server. How write the code depends on some factors related to your server configuration.
A really simple solution (if your server support [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)) can be something like:

```
getServerData.php

<?php
 echo   file_get_contents('http://www.rockfm.mx/jsonApps/jsonAlAire.php');
?>
```

Then, call getServeData.php with your script. With this little trick you will bypass same-origin restriction.

hope it help

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `http://`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
});
$("#loaduserdata").click(function(){
    $("#userdata tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON(
        "http://www.rockfm.mx/jsonApps/jsonAlAire.php",
        function(data){
            $.each(data.userdata, function(i,user){
                var tblRow =
                    "<tr>"
                    +"<td>"+user.tituloDelShow+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+user.locutores+"</td>"
                    +"</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            });
        }
    );
});
</script>
```